# How to get MigraDoc to produce PDF with dynamic page width?

Tags: c#, .net, migradoc

I have a PDF doc that I am trying to create, with about 20 columns, varying width. It gets about half of the columns on the first page and then cuts off the rest.I would like it to determine the page width and move the remaining columns onto the second page. Is there a way to specify this in rendering or PageSetup? I think I'll have to calculate the width, create the first page and then create the second.

```
Table table = new Table();

PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
renderer.Document = doc;
doc.DefaultPageSetup.Orientation = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Orientation.Landscape;

//create the columns
for (int i = 1; i < tripReportGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
       col = table.AddColumn(tripReportGrid.Columns[i].Width);
       col.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
    }

...fill the content same way

renderer.RenderDocument();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the page is what you set - or A4 if you set nothing.

You can set the width of the page to any value. That will probably be OK when viewing the PDF file on the screen.

Or you can only add as many columns to one table as fit on one page. A4 in landscape format is 29.7 cm. Default margins are 2.5 cm left and right.

And BTW: you should never modify the DefaultPageSetup. Assign a `Clone()` of the DefaultPageSetup to the PageSetup of your Section and change that as needed.

Comment: thanks, whats the best way to add a page, after the first one has been created?

Comment: You can call `AddPageBreak()` for your section to force a page break before the second table. You can call `AddSection()` for your document to create a new section (this implicitly leads to a page break). The new section can use a different page format, so if you decide to use custom page formats, a new section for the second table will allow you to use a different page width, too.